# how to create pagination with React

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, api, pagination

I get data from [github api](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=100)

I have all the data i need to display, but I want to splice it so that i only get 20 repositories per page.

And I don't want a framework or a plugin for that.

I'm fairly new to React and JS in general so I don't know where to start or what to do next to create a pagination.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class Apirequest extends Component {
    constructor(){
         super();
         this.state = {
             githubData: [],
         };
     } 
     componentDidMount() {
       axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=100')
       .then(res => {
         console.log('res', res)
         this.setState({ githubData: res.data.items})
       })
     }

     render() {
       const { githubData } = this.state
         return(
             <div className="container">
                 {githubData.map((name, index) => 
                   <table key={name.id}>
                    <tr>   
                     <th><img src={name.owner.avatar_url}/></th>
                     <td>{name.owner.login}<div className="border-bottom"></div></td>
                     <td>{name.description}<div className="border-bottom"></div></td>
                     <td><a href={name.homepage}>{name.homepage}</a></td>
                    </tr> 
                 </table> 
                 )}
             </div>
         )
     }
 }
export default Apirequest;
```

Comment: Your question is really broad. You may get better replies if you ask more specific questions. I believe what you want to know is how to go about creating a pagination. I'm sure if you search around on StackOverflow you'll find plenty of existing questions that have answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `map` function has a wrong logic. You are creating a table for each record and you should only create a row for each record. `table` tags should be outside of map.

```
 render() {
   const { githubData } = this.state
     return(
         <div className="container">
           <table key={name.id}>
             {githubData.map((name, index) => 
                <tr>   
                 <th><img src={name.owner.avatar_url}/></th>
                 <td>{name.owner.login}<div className="border-bottom"></div></td>
                 <td>{name.description}<div className="border-bottom"></div></td>
                 <td><a href={name.homepage}>{name.homepage}</a></td>
                </tr> 
             )}
           </table> 
         </div>
     )
 }
```

For pagination what you can do is to limit the number of rows you show by using [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Just to give you an idea I am posting a small example. You might need to implement some more for this logic to work on your code.

**Example**

```
previousPage = () => {
  if (this.state.currentPage !== 1)
    this.setState((prevState) => ({currentPage: (prevState.currentPage - 1)}))
}

nextPage = () => {
  if (this.state.currentPage + 1 < this.state.githubData.lenght)
    this.setState((prevState) => ({currentPage: (prevState.currentPage + 1)}))
}

 render() {
   const { githubData, currentPage } = this.state
     return(
         <div className="container">
           <table key={name.id}>
             {githubData.slice((currentPage * 20), 20).map((name, index) => 
                <tr>   
                 <th><img src={name.owner.avatar_url}/></th>
                 <td>{name.owner.login}<div className="border-bottom"></div></td>
                 <td>{name.description}<div className="border-bottom"></div></td>
                 <td><a href={name.homepage}>{name.homepage}</a></td>
                </tr> 
             )}
           </table>
           <button onClick={this.previousPage}>Previous Page</button>
           <button onClick={this.nextPage}>Next Page</button>
         </div>
     )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

set your state to have pagination info and data.

such as

```
state = {
 pagination: {
  start: 0,
  rows: 20
 },
 githubData: ....
}
```

and now in you render function you can splice based on the pagination info. Anytime new page is clicked, you can set state to new start variable